# Storing form data using cookies/sessions

Tags: php, forms, cookies, session-cookies

so i had an assignment to make an **"order form"** in which a user can reenter different data multiple times these datas are each time stored in a cookie (by clicking the add button) when the user is satisfied he then completes his purchase(by clicking the verify and the order is shown) and the order is stored in a text file (by clicking the store button)
here's my code :
the file name is : command.php

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="command.php" method="POST" class="formulaire">
            <fieldset>
                <legend> saisie d'article</legend>
                    <div class="elements_form">
                        <div class="elements">
                        <label for="code">code </label> <input type="textfield" name="code" placeholder="code de l'article">
                        </div>
                        <div class="elements">
                        <label for="article">article</label> <input type="textfield" name="article" placeholder="nom de l'article">
                        </div>
                        <div class="elements">
                        <label for="prix">prix </label> <input type="textfield" name="prix" placeholder="prix">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bouton">
                    <input class="bouton" name="ajouter" type="submit" value="ajouter">
                    <input class="bouton" name="enregistrer" type="submit" value="enregistrer">
                    <input class="bouton" name="verifier" type="submit" value="verifier">
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    
                    if(isset($_POST['ajouter'])){
                    $code=$_POST['code'];
                    $article=$_POST['article'];
                    $prix=$_POST['prix'];

                    $bon = isset($_COOKIE['$bon']) ? $_COOKIE['bon']:'[]';
                    $bon = json_decode($bon);

                    array_push($bon,array('code'=>$code,'article'=>$article,'prix'=>$prix));
                    setcookie('bon',json_encode($bon),time()+3000);
                    }
                    else if(isset($_POST['enregistrer'])){
                         $bon=$_COOKIE['bon'];
                         $monBon=json_encode($bon);
                         $mesBons=fopen(bon.txt,"a");
                         fwrite($mesBons,$monBon);
                         fwrite($mesBons,"\n");
                         fclose($mesBons);
                    }
                    else if(isset($_POST['verifier'])){
                         $bon=$_COOKIE['bon'];
                         $monBon=json_encode($bon);
                         echo "votre commande est comme suit:  ".$monBon;
                    }
                    ?>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
        
    </div>
</body>
```

what i had as a result tho is that my code only does one entry of data if the user reenters data it's gonna reset the cookie (and change it's data with the new entry)
i need help i want to to store multiple datas  in one cookie and each time make it add up to it not delete the old one until he completes the order to reset it ...

Comment: `$bon = isset($_COOKIE['$bon']) ? $_COOKIE['bon']:'[]';` <-- That's wierd. Look at the `'$bon'` and the `'[]'`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller i did this to say that my cookie can also be null is this a mistake ??

Comment: That syntax is correct. but I suppose you want `$bon = isset($_COOKIE['bon']) ? $_COOKIE['bon'] : [];` or simpler written as `$bon = $_COOKIE['bon'] ?? [];`.

Comment: Okey i'ma try it and see